# Including Foundation 5 in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript

I have created a theme from scratch using the CSS of Foundation 5, by overriding the Magento base template. Everything is fine with the CSS. However, when I include the Javascript of Foundation, some Magento plugins aren't working anymore.

So my question is: What is the proper way to include Foundation 5 and all of it's javascript features?

Here is the site I am using it [goo.gl/OaE08J](http://goo.gl/OaE08J) .

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible issue can be the conflict between prototypejs and the js used by Foundation 5, BTW which js does it use??

Comment: It is using Prototype 1.7.

Comment: I'm no expert in Founsation 5, but from what I can see it uses jquery. If this is the case you have to use jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: I have added the noConflict(), no results.

Answer (score 1):

It will be causing a conflict with prototype, the $ variable is used by both jQuery and Prototype.

To include Foundation or any jQuery you will either need to namespace your plugins or call noConflict, I use the following:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

This way you can still use the familiar $ syntax in jQuery.

You can read more here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: It still doesn't work. Here goo.gl/SUXMIU . If you click one of the icons on the footer, there displays a modal(Foundations Revealer). But I have installed a image zoom plugin, which doesn't work when I try to load the Foundation javascripts.